# RestEasy, JBoss Seam enigmatic exception

Tags: seam, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm using RestEasy within a JBoss Seam application and I am getting a weird exception which is not very informative. I have the following jars in my Seam 2.2.2.GA application:

- jaxrs-api-2.2.0.GA.jar
- resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.0.GA.jar
- jboss-seam-resteasy-2.2.0.GA.jar

I have setup a path to my resource like so:

```
@Path("/chartSvc")
@Stateless
@Name("chartAction")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class ChartAction implements Serializable, ChartActionLocal{

public ChartAction() {}

@GET
@Path("/populateChart")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String populateChart() {
String chartData = generateDummyChartData();
return chartData;
}
```

Now when I try to access my URL at /seam/resource/svc/chartSvc/populateChart, I get this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:63)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.PathSegmentImpl.parseSegments(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
    org.jboss.seam.resteasy.ResteasyResourceAdapter.extractUriInfo(ResteasyResourceAdapter.java:198)
    org.jboss.seam.resteasy.ResteasyResourceAdapter$1.process(ResteasyResourceAdapter.java:128)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.ContextualHttpServletRequest.run(ContextualHttpServletRequest.java:53)
    org.jboss.seam.resteasy.ResteasyResourceAdapter.getResource(ResteasyResourceAdapter.java:121)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet.service(SeamResourceServlet.java:80)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:63)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
```

My resource is never touched which indicates that this is probably something with my setup but I don't know where to begin to debug as I am sure I have all the right versions of the libraries. Can anyone help me to begin to debug this? This is my first seam application.

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be a version incompatibility between rest easy-jaxrs.jar and jboss-seam-resteasy.jar. The jboss-seam-resteasy.jar was at 2.2.0.GA and so was the rest easy-jaxrs.jar. However, you need resteasy-jaxrs.jar-1.1-RC2.jar to work with jboss-seam-resteasy-2.2.0.GA.jar. That jar replacement fixed my issue.